# How to define an animation and call it repetitively?

Tags: animation

I am new to blender and I am pretty sure there is such a feature in blender, I just don't know with which keyword do I have to search for it.

Let say I have a ball and I have animated one time jumping, now I need to repeat this for 10 more times, there should be a way to call this jumping repeatedly right? 
Also for the same object I may define lots of different animation, eg I have jumping animation and I have moving animation, then I want to say do 10 jumping and 2 movung then again five jumpping.

For animating I am using keyframes at the bottom of the main panel of blender.

Comment: have you learnt how to use the NLA editor?

Comment: try to change the interpolation to linear in graph editor

Comment: @moonboots that is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks